# Fetch and track some remote branch, but to a new worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

How can I fetch a branch from a repository but checkout to a new worktree?

Something like:

```
> git fetch origin releases/gcc-13
From git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc
 * branch                    releases/gcc-13 -> FETCH_HEAD
> git worktree add ../gcc-13 releases/gcc-13
fatal: invalid reference: releases/gcc-13
```

What I do not want is to checkout that branch to the current working directory (where `.git` is located) but to a new folder `../gcc-13`.

`git branch` does not show `releases/gcc-13`. AFAIU I'd have to do something like

```
> git checkout --track origin/releases/gcc-13
```

but that would checkout `gcc-13` to the current path, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this line:

```
 * branch                    releases/gcc-13 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

`git fetch` didn't store the downloaded branch (named `releases/gcc-13` on the remote side) to a "regular" tracking branch on the local side, but to the pseudo-ref `FETCH_HEAD`. This happened because you gave an explicit branch name on the `git fetch` command:

```
git fetch origin releases/gcc-13
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here
```

The next thing you should do is provide a branch name for the downloaded commits:

```
git branch releases/gcc-13 FETCH_HEAD
```

Now you can check out the branch in its own worktree.

```
git worktree add ../gcc-13 releases/gcc-13
```

Notable things:

- The local branch created with `git branch` is at this point completely unrelated to the remote branch of the same name. They just happen to be the same name and point to the same commit *at this time*.
- Using this procedure of not having a local branch right away, is totally normal when you want to do some "sight-seeing" in random branches downloaded from more or less random remote repositories. You are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: After removing the branch, I started again with the commands as you proposed. All appears to work, but when I `cd` to the new worktree and try to update it with `git pull`  am getting errors `You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them. ...` I don't have any changes in the worktree, I just want to track how GCC is evolving. In the `master` though, `git pull` works fine.

Comment: A simple `git pull` will not know what to do because, as I said in the answer, the branch is not connected to the upstream branch. You can fix that using `git branch --set-upstream-to` (read [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt), I don't know how to operate it), or use `git pull origin releases/gcc-13` to tell explicitly which remote branch to merge.

Comment: Ok, so  the three command that you wrote in your answer are not a solution to the problem? If I always have to explicitly type some branches that's error prone. The branch is connected to the remote branch and is tracking it, no? So what does "tracking" mean at all?

Comment: The problem that this answer solves (and it does solve it) is that your `git worktree` command produced an error. That your `git pull` does not work as expected is a different question that deserves its own answer. I'm pretty sure that you can find a lot of answers to that question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git worktree add --track -b <branch> <path> <remote>/<branch>
```

If  is omitted and neither -b nor -B nor --detach used, then, as a convenience, the new worktree is associated with a branch (call it ) named after $(basename ).

If  doesn't exist, a new branch based on HEAD is automatically created as if -b  was given.
If  does exist, it will be checked out in the new worktree, if it's not checked out anywhere else, otherwise the command will refuse to create the worktree (unless --force is used).

Comment: With `git worktree add --track -b releases/gcc-13 ../gcc-13 remote/releases/gcc-13` I am getting "error: the requested upstream branch 'remote/releases/gcc-13' does not exist". Same with `origin/releases/gcc-13` or just `releases/gcc-13`. But the branch is there: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/releases/gcc-13